# Full screen display for Ubuntu 16.04 on Virtualbox 6.0.4

Tags: virtualbox

I installed Virtualbox 6.0.4 on Debian Jessie 8. I want to run a Ubuntu 16.04 32 bit VM that I have. In previous virtual box versions, the VM would boot into a full screen.

In version 6.0.4, the VM does not show a full screen. I have tried installing guest additions and virtual box extension pack, but it hasn't solved the problem. I also tried changing the resolution from inside the VM, but it doesn't solve the problem. Does anyone know what else can be done to make the VM display full screen in virtual box 6.0.4 ?

Comment: Does right ctrl+F works?

Comment: @PRY It does not work. It goes to full screen with VM display in the middle and lot of black color all around it.